# MonacaアプリでiPhone版の画面が通知領域まで影響してしまうのを防ぐ方法

Tags: ios, monaca

お世話になっております。

MonacaアプリでiPhone版の画面が通知領域まで影響してしまうのを防ぎたいです。

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

このソースの`height=device-height`の部分で、縦の画面サイズをデバイスに合わせるものだと思っておりますが、解釈が間違っているのでしょうか？
文字やボタンが通知領域に重なって表示されているのを、重ならないように設定したいと考えております。

ご指摘よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

通知領域と言うのはステータスバーのことでしょうか？
そうであれば[ステータスバープラグイン](http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/reference/phonegap_3.5/ja/statusbar/)を使用しましょう。

```
StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
```

設定 > Cordovaプラグインの管理から確認してください

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
ステータスバーのことで違いありません。
Cordovaプラグインの管理から有効にしましたが、変わりませんでした。
'StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);'はどこで確認すればいいのでしょうか？
引き続き、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: リンク先は閲覧しましたでしょうか？プラグインを有効にするだけでは解決しません。上記解答はステータスバーにオーバーレイするのを無効にする`JavaScript`の命令になります。プラグインを有効にしたうえで上記の命令をアプリ開始時に入れるか、`plist`ファイルを編集しステータスバー自体を表示しないようにするかの２択です。

Comment: アプリ開始時に挿入し実行したところ、エラー（画面もログも出力されず）で止まってしまいました。（うまく書けていないだけかもしれません。）
もう一つの方法でステータスバーを非表示にすることは成功しましたので、当面はこれで妥協しつつ、エラーの原因を調べて修正していくことにします。
`StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);` で不明な点が残れば、また改めて質問させて頂くかもしれません。
この度は、ありがとうございました。